# Does $P(A\mid B)$ determine $P(A\mid \bar{B})$?

Tags: probability, conditional-probability

I'm sorry if this is a stupid question, but if $P(A\mid B)$ is fixed, does this uniquely determine $P(A \mid \bar{B})$?

Comment: The answer is a big NO.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy Could you explain why not? Or refer me to an explanation in a book?

Comment: "Why not" should be obtained using the definition of conditional expectation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Do you see how these Venn diagrams show why the answer is NO?

[image]